# statement with only a variable name

Tags: c++, variables

I just saw a guy did this today when I was studying his code fragment:

```
void doSomething(int param) {
    // stuffs
    param; // <-- what does this statement do?
    // stuffs
}
```

I tried looking for it on the internet and asked most of my friends about it but this one looks alien to them too. So guys, what does that statement do really?

Comment: If `param` isn't otherwise used, it's there to prevent warning about unused parameter. Other than that, it's got no effect. It might trigger another differerent warning about statement having no effect, though.

Comment: Most likely stops the compiler complaining about an unused parameter. But then it will complain that statement has no effect. (Well actually they are separate options, but probably this is being compiled with groups of warnings, such as `-Wall -Wextra`).

Comment: A follow on question: if this was an inline function then could it have the same behaviour as a gcc statement expression; normally used in macros?

Comment: You can also see `(void)param;` or things like `UNUSED(param);` (macro) or `use(param);` (template function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may serve to remove a warning about unused parameters.  But logically it does nothing.  There are better ways to remove the warning about an unused parameter.  Using a macro:

```
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( param );
```

Or by removing the name of the parameter from the function:

```
void doSomething(int /*param*/) { ...
```

I prefer the latter, because it means that `param` is definitely not used.  I've seen instances of `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER` being specified, then later in the code the parameter is actually used.

Answer (score 3):

It was probably put in to silence compiler warning about "unused formal parameter." That is, the parameter is (currently) not used anywhere else in the function, so this use is introduced to remove the warning.

There are several other ways to do this, e.g. casting it to `void`:

```
(void)param;
```

However, they all suffer from the same drawback: they are equally valid if the parameter is actually used. So it's fairly possible you see them at the top of the function, think "OK, it doesn't use `param`," and then be surprised when it *does* use it later.

That's why I prefer to comment out the parameter name if it's not used. The identifier stays there for code readability, but no warning is given, and if you later change the code to use the parameter, you must explicitly uncomment it or you get an error.